# Why does this javascript throw an undefined error?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to define my own onblur event for all text boxes in an application so that I can strip all high ascii values, so I wrote a script that runs on an asp.net master page that runs per page load, overriding all text box / area onblur events, and storing a copy of the old event.

The new event then called the old event so it wouldn't break existing events across the forms.

It worked fine until a page defined an onblur like: onblur="func(this)"
When the original event fires the 'this' point doesn't seem to point to the sender control any longer.

[Pastebin link with 2 simple examples](http://pastebin.com/Ympx1jF9)

So would anyone be able to point me towards a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a function dynamically while controlling the value of `this`, use func.apply instead of a standard call. For example instead of

`myStoredFunc(arg1, arg2)`

use :

`myStoredFunc.apply(this, arguments);`

This way the value of the this variable will be correctly passed to the called function, thanks to `apply`'s first argument. The second argument allows you to specify the parameter values (here I pass all the current function's arguments to the called function).